# Conditionally execute query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to execute a query, depending on the result of a certain column?

My table has a column `col1`, which could be `NULL`. I want to check first. If `col1` is not NULL, execute another query, if `col1` is NULL, do nothing (or return something else).

In pseudocode it could look like this:

```
IF (SELECT col1 IS NUT NULL FROM `tab1`)
THEN (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM `tab1`)
```

*PS: I execute those queries from PHP, so it would also be possible, to check the result of `col1` with PHP, though I would prefer to use plain SQL.*

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/functions-conditional.html

Comment: This is just a WHERE clause: `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

the where clause is your if

```
  select col1, col2, col3 FROM `tab1`
  where col1 IS NOT NULL
```